# Black holes in p-adic gravity/ultra-metric metric field?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon, topology

As a radically different to beyond standard general relativity, at least from the type of geometry it deals with:

1. Consider p-adic gravity and/or general relativity defined on certain ultra-metric spacetime where we have "a metric".
2. Consider the concept of black hole solution (I have no reference of any ansatz of this typer for these theories), if any!

**Question:** do black hole solutions exist, in the classical set-up (i.e.vacuum solutions) for p-adic gravity and/or general relativity formulated on p-adic numbers or an ultrametric (likely adelic) field on which we define "a metric"?

(Note: I am well aware maybe I can NOT define a standard metric on a p-adic or adelic sense).

Comment: I don't think it means anything very well-defined to talk about a "non-archimedean geometry" in this context. For example, you can take a manifold M and extend it to *M, as in NSA, but nothing really special happens then; it just allows you a mathematical convenience, as when we do calculus using infinitesimals. See  http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.0984 . Or you can do differential geometry using synthetic differential geometry, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186851/synthetic-vs-classical-differential-geometry . But there is no new geometry or physics there, just a different formalism.

Comment: Well, a Kerr black hole is actually a black hole with a pretty exotic topology :) Another one would be the NUT space-time in the cyclical universe completion. The thing is that you can do a whole lot when you drop asymptotic flatness (or asymptotic dS/AdS), but if you have Einstein equations and asymptotic flatness, you cannot. The case is similar with exotic geometries at least from what I have seen; if it has flat spacetime physics, it is not really an exotic geometry, if it has an actually exotic geometry, it has no normal physics.

Comment: A "solution" of what?

Comment: @safesphere I think I clarified that...

Comment: @riemannium: I don't think you really did clarify that. The field equations are posed as tensor equations on a real manifold. If you're talking about something that's not the real number system, then they aren't solutions of the same equations.

Comment: @BenCrowell Following Volovich et al., you can indeed formulate the EFE on non-archimedean fields. That was the origin of my question...Suppose we can create a meaningful notion of non-archimedean manifold or alike, what would be an ultrametric black hole look-like? If any...

Comment: Have a look here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.04758. This is a recent review and most of the works cited on p-adic gravity deals with cosmology.

Comment: I know that paper...But again, the real problem, maybe I should reedit my question, is that I don't know about black holes in p-adic or ultrametric gravity beyond naive mentions. So, I should reask, maybe, if we DO KNOW if black holes exist in p-adic/ultrametric/non-archimedean gravity?@A.V.S.?What do yo think?

Comment: I have improved, I believe, my question now...

Comment: @riemannium: If you have references that help to explain what you have in mind here, please edit the question so that it includes the references.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simpler (from a mathematical perspective) black holes is the [BTZ black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BTZ_black_hole) which is the solution of a 3D gravity with negative cosmological constant. Einstein equations ensure that spacetime is locally an $\text{AdS}_3$  space and this solution could be seen as a factor of $\text{AdS}_3$  space by a discrete group. So, the p-adic generalization of the BTZ black hole would be a p-adic version of $\text{AdS}_3$  factored by some discrete group. Gravity as such does not  enter this reasoning. Such realization of p-adic BTZ black hole has been constructed by  Matthew Heydeman, Matilde Marcolli and others in [1,2].

Here is a picture of a 3-adic BTZ black hole from [ 1]:

[image: image from 1605.07639]

Some explanation. p-adic version of $\text{AdS}_3$ space is represented by the  Bruhat–Tits tree for $\mathrm{PGL}(2,\mathbb{Q}_p)$, the infinite tree of uniform valence $p+1$, such as this one (here $p=2$):

[image: image from 1605.07639]

Factoring this tree by a discrete Schottky group means that there would be different points of the tree that we must identify, thus forming cycles. And such a cycle means that we now have the black hole.

While such a construct may seem very abstract, it is straightforward to think about realization of Bruhat–Tits tree on a hyperbolic space $H_2$ as a spatial slice of the $\text{AdS}_3$  space, and the trees growing from a cycle (as in the first image) would be a spatial slice of a BTZ black hole spacetime.

Original papers:

1. Matthew Heydeman, Matilde Marcolli, Ingmar Saberi, Bogdan Stoica, *Tensor networks, p-adic fields, and algebraic curves: arithmetic and the $\text{AdS}_3/\text{CFT}_2$  correspondence*, [arXiv:1605.07639](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.07639).
2. Heydeman, M., Marcolli, M., Parikh, S., & Saberi, I. *Nonarchimedean Holographic Entropy from Networks of Perfect Tensors*, [arXiv:1812.04057](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.04057)

Talks, lectures by the authors:

3. Talk “Non-Archimedean Holography” by M. Marcolli: [Slides](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~matilde/MPIArbeitstagungSlides.pdf), [Video here](https://www.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/node/7426).
4. Talk “AdS/CFT and p-Adic Numbers: A Model of Discrete Holography” by M. Heydeman: [Slides](https://stringmath2017.desy.de/sites/sites_conferences/site_stringmath2017/content/e45470/e56510/e56544/SM-Heydeman.pdf), [Video](https://webcast.desy.de/?p=7646).